# How to explode vaules in $_GET['']=1#5#6 in php?

Tags: php, url, get, explode

Hi in my url i have variables stored in    ../index.php?cat=1#5#8     in so on how to separate them using explode function so out put could be

```
arr[0]=1
arr[1]=5
arr[2]=8
```

Comment: [Have you tried anything?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) - this is a trivial question, especially since you already know the function to use.

Comment: If possible I'd suggest changing the URL. 'yoursite/?cat%5B%5D=1&cat%5B%5D=2&cat%5B%5D=3' would actually give you the array you're looking for, directly. Not posting as answer as I can't assume  you can change the url, just wanted to throw it out there :)

Comment: can you change `#` char?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `explode` like

```
$arr = explode("#",$_GET['cat']);
```

But as @Bora said after `#` the remaining string will may not be sent ,so better to use '_' in place of '#' (1_5_8_....)and can explode it like

```
$arr = explode("_",$_GET['cat']);
```

Comment: The part after the # doesn't get sent to the server.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$array=$_GET['cat'];

$result = explode("#",$array);
```

Comment: The part after the # doesn't get sent to the server.